# Android TextInputEditText, inputType = textPassword, I can't see dots

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

I use TextInputEditText in my activity. I set inputType 'textPassword'.
But I can not see dots to protect the password I entered.

This is my view source codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_background_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/intro_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_logo_img"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/rock_bottom_logo" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_email_layout"
        style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_logo_img"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_login_email_txt"
            style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_login_email_txt"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_password_layout"
        style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_email_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_login_password_txt"
            style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_login_password_txt"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/email_login_sign_in_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_password_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom_login"
        android:text="@string/email_login_sign_in_txt"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_sign_up_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_login_sign_in_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/email_login_sign_up_txt"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_password_find_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_login_sign_up_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/email_login_sign_up_txt"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is screenshot that shows my problem.

[image]

It may not look good, but the dot is definitely not visible at all.

And this is style that is applied to my activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorDarkerGray</item>
    </style>
```

How can i solve this problem. I need your help. Thank you.

Additionally, This is my EmailTextInputEditText Style.

```
<style name="EmailTextInputEditText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#a90000</item>
    <item name="android:textCheckMark">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Additionally, This is my color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#c20000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#ea0000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="colorBlack">@android:color/black</color>
    <color name="colorVideoTxt">#001020</color>
    <color name="colorVideoTransparent">#92dadada</color>
    <color name="colorDarkerGray">@android:color/darker_gray</color>
    <color name="white">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="cardBackground">#73e2e2e2</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00ffffff</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: please share **`EmailTextInputEditText`** style with question

Comment: It has something to do with the InputStyling for the password input field. Please share the related code along with your question.

Comment: Check your textcolor inside edittext. I think its color is black.

Comment: @NileshRathod Oh my mistake. Sorry, now I add that.

Comment: @AbhishekDS I edit my question. Please check it.

Comment: @AIK Actually, textColor is white :(

Comment: try changing your theme for edittext style or try after removing it.

Comment: Your code is already working, Did you test on device or emulator?

Comment: @AIK Sure... I really don't know why.. Is there any correct design library version or api level to use TextInputEditText?

Comment: @HareshChhelana My code working? It's really weird. I run my app in emulator but It does not work. My device too.

Comment: Have you tried the answers yet? Please also post your colors.xml

Comment: @AIK I tried it. but It does not work.. I add Color.xml in my question. Really appreciate for your answer.

Comment: Now the only thing remaining is to remove your edittext style lines one by one and run project each time to check which line is creating the problem. Also check waht happens if you don't apply style to your edittext.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/background"
    android:textColorHint="@color/background">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtxtUsrID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email ID"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/view_grey"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/view_grey"
    android:textColorHint="@color/view_grey">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtxtUsrPswrd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/view_grey"
        android:textColorHint="@color/view_grey" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

@Junburg You added -  style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText" in `TextInputEditText` remove that line from `TextInputEditText`,see below screenshot[image]

Comment: Instead of put bulk of code try to explain what he's doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: I add backgroundTint and textColorHint, but it's not works '~'

Comment: I tried to tell you to. But it does not work. I really do not know why. Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: @Dhanshri, Is it working with constraint-layout?  Can I customize it?

Answer (score 1):

The  issue with your theme try the below code

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/goku" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_logo_img"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_email_layout"
        style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_logo_img"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_login_email_txt"
            style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="email_login_email_txt"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_password_layout"
        style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_email_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_login_password_txt"
            style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="email_login_password_txt"
            android:text="123456"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/email_login_sign_in_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_password_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="email_login_sign_in_txt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_sign_up_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_login_sign_in_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="email_login_sign_up_txt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_password_find_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_login_sign_up_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="email_login_sign_up_txt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> THEMES

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#787777</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EmailTextInputEditText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#a90000</item>
        <item name="android:textCheckMark">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

**RESULT USING WITH IMAGEVIEW**

[image]

**NOTE** :  also no need of extra `imageView` remove it and just set background to your `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/goku">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_logo_img"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_email_layout"
        style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_logo_img"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_login_email_txt"
            style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="email_login_email_txt"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_password_layout"
        style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_email_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_login_password_txt"
            style="@style/EmailTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="email_login_password_txt"
            android:text="123456"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/email_login_sign_in_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_login_password_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="email_login_sign_in_txt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_sign_up_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_login_sign_in_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="email_login_sign_up_txt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_login_password_find_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_login_sign_up_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="email_login_sign_up_txt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RESULT USING WITHOUT IMAGEVIEW**

[image]

Comment: I have to use scaleType centerCrop to my background image. So I have to use ImageView. And I apply your theme but it's not works. But I really appreciate for your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Oh you are really kind. But in my case, backgroud image in relativelayout It's crumbled. I tried this solution before.